# add class second id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem and I can't figure out how to solve it and I thank you already in advance for your time.

I cannot add a class to an id via js, the original idea was to apply two classes when the input is clicked. Unfortunately only the first one works and the "link" class is not applied to that id (#boxlink).

I will leave you the code and thank you

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".namebutton").click(function () {
        var div= $("#"+this.value);
              div.toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
          $("#buttons").addClass('crossRotate');
          $("#boxlink").addClass('link');
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000!important;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 300;
  width:100%;
  height:900px;
}

h5 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size:60px;
}

.lefteffect {
  transform: translateX(-300px);
}

.testo-descrizione {
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
}

.movimento {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.buttonsclass {
  display: table;
}

.brandname, .serviceclass, .b2bclass {
  display: table-row;
}

.tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
display:none;
}

.content-2 {
display: inline-block;
}

.fullwidth {
  width:100%;
}

.content-33 {
 width:40%;
display: inline-block;
}

.content-3 {
transition-property: left, right;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-delay: 0s;
}

#buttons > h5 {
  margin-bottom:4%;
}

.crossRotate {
  animation: button 2s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes button {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
}

.brandproject1{
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(210 57 73);
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}

.link {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" style="height: 900px;">
      <div class="col">
         <div class="buttonsclass" style="height: 900px;margin: auto;">
            <div id="buttons" class="btn tablecell" style="width:90px">
                <h5><input type="button" id="button1" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="Brand"></input></h5>
                <h5><input type="button" id="button2" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="Servizi"> </input></h5>
                <h5><input type="button" id="button3" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="B2B"></input></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="#boxlink" class="brandproject1 tablecell" style="width:150px">
              <div id="Brand" style="display:none">
                 <span><a href="#">1</a></span><br> 
                 <span><a href="#/">2</a></span>
              </div>
              <div id="Servizi" style="display:none">
                 <span><a href="#">2</a></span><br> 
                 <span><a href="#">2</a></span>
              </div>
              <div id="B2B" style="display:none">
                 <span><a href="#">3</a></span><br> 
                 <span><a href="#">3</a></span>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id="#boxlink"` is incorrect, it actually puts a `#` **in** the `id`. Then your ID selector (the `#` means "what follows is an ID, go find it") fails because there is no element with the ID `boxlink` (just `#boxlink`). If you fix the ID on the element (`id="boxlink"`), it will find the element and add the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div id="#boxlink" ...>` is your error. In css selectors, `#` means an id property, avoid it in the id value (`<div id="boxlink" ...>`).

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".namebutton").click(function () {
        var div= $("#"+this.value);
              div.toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
          $("#buttons").addClass('crossRotate');
          $("#boxlink").addClass('link');
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000!important;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 300;
  width:100%;
  height:900px;
}

h5 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size:60px;
}

.lefteffect {
  transform: translateX(-300px);
}

.testo-descrizione {
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
}

.movimento {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.buttonsclass {
  display: table;
}

.brandname, .serviceclass, .b2bclass {
  display: table-row;
}

.tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
display:none;
}

.content-2 {
display: inline-block;
}

.fullwidth {
  width:100%;
}

.content-33 {
 width:40%;
display: inline-block;
}

.content-3 {
transition-property: left, right;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-delay: 0s;
}

#buttons > h5 {
  margin-bottom:4%;
}

.crossRotate {
  animation: button 2s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes button {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
}

.brandproject1{
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(210 57 73);
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}

.link {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" style="height: 900px;">
      <div class="col">
         <div class="buttonsclass" style="height: 900px;margin: auto;">
            <div id="buttons" class="btn tablecell" style="width:90px">
                <h5><input type="button" id="button1" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="Brand"></input></h5>
                <h5><input type="button" id="button2" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="Servizi"> </input></h5>
                <h5><input type="button" id="button3" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="B2B"></input></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="boxlink" class="brandproject1 tablecell" style="width:150px">
              <div id="Brand" style="display:none">
                 <span><a href="#">1</a></span><br> 
                 <span><a href="#/">2</a></span>
              </div>
              <div id="Servizi" style="display:none">
                 <span><a href="#">2</a></span><br> 
                 <span><a href="#">2</a></span>
              </div>
              <div id="B2B" style="display:none">
                 <span><a href="#">3</a></span><br> 
                 <span><a href="#">3</a></span>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This falls into "typo" territory (though I'm sure there are multiple duplicates as well). We don't post *answers* to typos / duplicates on SO. Instead, find the previous question (if any) and vote to close (either as duplicate or typo).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's those things you don't see as long as you see them....

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for letting me know, will do next time